# How can I cosume a GET REST call and mapping to a java bean (object) through Apache Camel?

Tags: apache, rest, spring-mvc, apache-camel

I am new in apache camel. I want to do a GET REST call to get data and then I want to mapping these data to my Java bean. How can I do that with camel? I want to do it in a spring MVC web application.

I know how to do it with RestTemplate for example, but I want to use apache camel.
I've checked this documentation http://camel.apache.org/cxfrs.html but still I don't know how to set up for accomplishing this.
Please if you can provide some examples will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different options. I'll walk through one...

First, define your rest configuration with **bindingMode=auto**

```
restConfiguration()
.component("jetty").host("0.0.0.0").port(9000)
.bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto);
```

Next, when you define your particular rest service, **specify a type** (this is the type of the incoming body:

```
rest("/")
.put("/A/{subpath1}/{subpath2}")
.type(MyPojo.class)
.to("direct:XYZ");
```

That's it! The unmarshalling will be magical ;)

Alternatively, you can unmarshal things yourself.

If you'd like to see a working example of the above, check out this program: it has a main() to test it. https://github.com/DariusX/CamelSandbox/blob/master/CamelSandbox/src/main/java/com/zerses/camelsandbox/rest/RestConsumerBindingTest.java